# Jaxon doesn´t return anything on response

Tags: ajax, php-7.3, xajax

Please, can anyone help?

I´m starting to use jaxon 3, planning to migrate from xajax. On a php7.3 plataform, I made a simple code, just to load jaxon and run a single alert script, but its returning nothing on browser. There are no errors on server log and no info on browser, no even on the chrome debug console.

Here is the simple code:

```
<?php


require_once( 'Jaxon/vendor/autoload.php' );
use Jaxon\Jaxon;
use Jaxon\Response\Response;

$ajax = jaxon();
$ajax->setOption('core.debug.on', false);

$ajax->setOption('core.prefix.function', 'jaxon_');

$ajax->setOption('core.request.uri', 'ajax.php');
$objResponse = new Response();



$objResponse->alert('test');
return $objResponse;
echo 'tests';
?>
```

PS: I didn´t use the jaxon word on tag cause the editor doesn´t let me do it

Answer (score 1):

I would tell you to delete the echo at the end, and try to code some functions even for testing, so you can better understand v3.

Here, check this code, it might help you, this code is tested and will work.

```
<?php
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Jaxon\Jaxon;
use Jaxon\Response\Response;

$jaxon = jaxon();

$jaxon->setOption('js.app.minify', TRUE);
$jaxon->setOption('js.lib.uri', '/vendor/jaxon-php/jaxon-js/dist');


/** ################################# */
/** using jaxon with just functions then you have to register each function 
 * 
 *  call these functions like this:
 *  jaxon_demo1();
 *  jaxon_demo2();
 * 
 *  <button type="button" onclick="jaxon_demo1()"> call fn 1 </button>
 *  <button type="button" onclick="jaxon_demo2()"> call fn 2 </button>
 *  
*/
$jaxon->register(Jaxon::USER_FUNCTION, 'demo1'); 
$jaxon->register(Jaxon::USER_FUNCTION, 'demo2'); 
$jaxon->register(Jaxon::CALLABLE_FUNCTION, 'functionThatReturnsUsing_setReturnValue', ['mode' => "'synchronous'"]); 

function demo1(){
    $jaxonResponse = new Response();
    $jaxonResponse->alert('Hello there, be sure to open browser console to see the console.log');
    $jaxonResponse->script("console.log('Hello there')");
    
    return $jaxonResponse;
}

function demo2(){
    $jaxonResponse = new Response();

    // <div id="theDiv"> this will be replaced </div>
    $jaxonResponse->assign("theDiv","innerHTML",'Some content that can even be a template if you implement smarty or similar');
    
    return $jaxonResponse;
}

/**
 *  check out https://github.com/jaxon-php/jaxon-js/issues/15
 *  this should work, take a look at the link provided
 *  also use the browser console to look the response data being returned
 */
function functionThatReturnsUsing_setReturnValue(){
    $jaxonResponse = new Response();
    // lets suppose you have a script like this
    // <script>
    //    function demo3(){
    //        var myData = jaxon_functionThatReturnsUsing_setReturnValue();
    //        console.log(myData);
    //    }   
    // </script>
    $someData = array(
    'isValidated' => TRUE,
    'str_data' => 'some data here',
    'int_data' => 123,
    'flt_data' => 1.23,
    'row_data' => array(
        'isValidated' => TRUE,
        'str_data' => 'some data here',
        'int_data' => 123,
        'flt_data' => 1.23
        )
    );
    $jaxonResponse->setReturnValue($someData);
    $jaxonResponse->getOutput();
    return $jaxonResponse;
}    
    
if($jaxon->canProcessRequest()){
    $jaxon->processRequest();
}

/**
 * if you are using composer, then your composer.json should have this at least:
 * 
 * {
 *     "require": {
 *         "jaxon-php/jaxon-core": "^3.2",
 *         "jaxon-php/jaxon-js": "^3.2"
 *     }
 * }
 * 
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Demo jaxon</title>
    <?php echo $jaxon->getCss(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jaxon_demo1()">demo fn 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jaxon_demo2()">demo fn 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="demo3()">demo fn 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="theDiv">this will be replaced</diV>
    
    <script>
        function demo3(){
            var myData = jaxon_functionThatReturnsUsing_setReturnValue();
            console.log(myData);
        }   
    </script>
    <?php
        echo $jaxon->getJs();
        echo $jaxon->getScript();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```